# i have a social media site where i update a code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Any One just add a one Function live cropping my profile pic then update

When i click update profile pic button then a popup come and then upload pic then cropping this upload pic then finally date into the database

Contant.phtml is the main index page:

```html
<div class="user-avatar flip">
  <div class="user-avatar-uploading-container">
    <div class="user-avatar-uploading-progress">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-spin progress-icon" data-icon="spin"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img id="updateImage-<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['user_id']?>" class="pointer" alt="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['name']?> Profile Picture" src="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['avatar']?>" onclick="Wo_OpenProfilePicture('<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['avatar_org']?>');" />
  <?php if($IsOwner === true) { ?>
    <form action="#" method="post" class="profile-avatar-changer">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <span class="btn btn-upload-image btn-file">
           <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
            <input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/x-png, image/jpeg" onchange="Wo_UpdateProfileAvatar();">
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user-id" value="<?php echo $wo['user_profile']['user_id'];?>">
    </form>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit complex process, you have to follow 2 things-

1. Javascript code for allowing users to zoom in and track the position of image from where to crop (x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3) (x4,y4) and scaled ratio.
2. Then you can use these dimension in image processing tools like ffmpeg or imagemagic.

[image: Something like this, you want to achieve?]